# Any way to open googlecast minicontroller seekbar?

Tags: android, google-cast, castcompanionlibrary

As you know while mini controller is open we can click and it opens the popup which includes seekbar. 
I have used the Cast Companion Library and other features works well.

```
            CastConfiguration options = new CastConfiguration.Builder(applicationId)
            .enableAutoReconnect()
            .enableCaptionManagement()
            .enableDebug()
            .enableLockScreen()
            .enableNotification()
            .enableWifiReconnection()
            .setCastControllerImmersive(true)
            .setLaunchOptions(false, Locale.getDefault())
            .setNextPrevVisibilityPolicy(CastConfiguration.NEXT_PREV_VISIBILITY_POLICY_DISABLED)
            .addNotificationAction(CastConfiguration.NOTIFICATION_ACTION_REWIND, false)
            .addNotificationAction(CastConfiguration.NOTIFICATION_ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE, true)
            .addNotificationAction(CastConfiguration.NOTIFICATION_ACTION_DISCONNECT, true)
            .setForwardStep(10)
            .build();
    VideoCastManager.initialize(this, options);
```

is there any way to enable this seekbar popup ?

I have debugged my code. VideoCastControllerActivity was not opened. I can provide more debug results to get help from you guys.

Comment: Fount solution. Forgot to declare 
VideoCastControllerActivity.java in AndroidManifest.xml